# How to create a Gson deserilization that handle all String in one way except one field?

Tags: java, gson

I have created a deserialization, that whenever it see the String "nil", it will return null.

```
private static Gson createCustomGson() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new JsonDeserializer<String>() {
        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
            return (json.getAsString().equals("nil")) ? null : json.getAsString();
        }
    });
    return gsonBuilder.create();
}
```

It works good except that, I want to add an exception where for the field "Keyword" that store a List, I don't want to eliminate nil to return null, but retain the String. How to add the exception for "Keyword"?

My Keyword class is of the below type

```
public class KeywordListing implements Serializable {
    List<String> keys;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. It's by adding another TypeAdapter to use back the default deserizliation from Gson instead as below.

```
private static Gson createCustomGson() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new JsonDeserializer<String>() {
        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
            return (json.getAsString().equals("nil")) ? null : json.getAsString();
        }
    });
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(KeywordListing.class, new JsonDeserializer< KeywordListing >() {
                @Override
                public KeywordListing deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
                    return new Gson().fromJson(json, KeywordListing.class);
                }
            });

    return gsonBuilder.create();
}
```

Let me know if there's a shorter answer than what I got above.